# Unable to enable Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to enable Bitbucket pipelines in a private repository. I go to "Pipelines" tag in the left menu, and then click on "Enable Pipelines" button.

Then, a "wait for it" spin icon appears in the middle of the screen.... and nothing more happen.

I tried uploading a bitbucket-pipelines.yml file with some apparently correct content, but nothing changed on the Pipelines page.

I tried with Chrome and Firefox. Is it a common issue?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue. There is a workaround to this if you remove the pipelines from the installed apps by going to `Home > Settings > Installed Apps > Pipelines > Click Remove`.

**This makes the Bitbucket reinstall the application and that resolves the bug.**

[image: Click on remove button]

Answer (score 1):

Have not seen that. Even free accounts should have pipelines enabled. Would try contacting Atlassian support.