# Bitbucket: How to enable pipelines for continuous integration

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to Bitbucket (I just created my account). And I would like to test their continuous integration tool **pipelines**. I have uploaded my source code to my account. But I can't see how I can activate this feature. There is an icon at the left navigation pane that says "Pipelines (New)". When I click it, it takes me to a blank screen. And then nothing happens.

My account is a free account (for test purpose for now). But this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065303/unable-to-enable-bitbucket-pipelines) says that even free accounts should have pipelines enabled.

From my settings, I don't see a setting to enable pipelines.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

### August 2022:

I had the same problem, seems that you can't use the pipeline feature if you don't have two factor authentication.

go to   [two step verification](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/two-step-verification/manage), do all the steps, and then you can just use the pipeline.

You can see the settings in:

Repository settings => scroll all the way down to "pipelines" =>
press the "Settings"

[image: where to find the settings]

And you'll get to this screen:

[image: the pipeline settings screen]

Or go directly to:

https://bitbucket.org/user-name/repo-name/admin/addon/admin/pipelines/settings

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to pop out the sidebar on the left and then there should be a pipelines icon there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I have already said in my question: "There is an icon at the left navigation pane that says "Pipelines (New)". When I click it, it takes me to a blank screen. And then nothing happens."

Comment: So I am already clicking the pipelines icons. But it takes me to a blank page. There is no "Enable pipelines" button in it...

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't understand that part, I'm not sure then. It worked for me on my account which is also free. 

Maybe try a different browser or different account? Or maybe login and out again?

Comment: What you are seeing is a bug, you can log a bug at https://support.atlassian.com you'll need to go contact technical support -> devtools -> bitbucket cloud. It doesn't matter that you have a free account you should be able to get help as it is a bug.